# Complex sentence and compound sentence?

Tags: grammar, subordinate-clauses, coordination, compound-complex

While reading, I get stuck by these two sentences:

> Even if the code hasn't changed, the system behavior can because the data we use to train our models determines the predictions we make.

> Chinese economic principles are not those of laissez-faire, nor of promoting the class struggle.

For the first one, if I am not wrong, "even if" is a subordinating conjunction, and then the main clause "the system behavior can" has two dependent clauses: "even if the code hasn't changed" and "because the data we use to train our models determines the predictions we make".

For the second one, I thought "nor" is a coordinating conjunction, and then the sentence is a simple sentence. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, *because* is also a subordinator. The main clause is then
*the system behavior can [change]*,
where the last word's meaning is implied.
So you have a main clause and a subordinate clause *even if...*.
Then you have final subordinate clause *because...*, which is subordinate to the combination of the first two clauses.

For the second example, I agree, it's simple. The sentence is like

> The principles are neither A nor B.

The coordination lacks parallelism. That could be corrected by inserting another *those* and deleting *promoting*:

> Chinese economic principles are not those of laissez-faire, nor *those* of the class struggle.